# Split a list into pairs using python

Tags: python, string, list, split, parentheses

I have a list/string. And I would like to split it into pairs and separate them by parenthesis in the same list as output. How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
ip='MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, NULL, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(22027, 22943.23, 22026, 22939, 22025, 22936, 22025.09, 22932, 22027, 22929, 22030, 22926)'
split_string_1 = "MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY("
split_string_2 = ")"

data = list(map(int, ip.split(split_string_1)[1].split(split_string_2)[0].split(", ")))

result = list(zip(data[:-1], data[1:]))
```

I get an error saying `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '22943.23'` How do I solve this?

Desired output:

```
[(22027, 22943.23), (22026, 22939), (22025, 22936), (22025.09, 22932), (22027, 22929), (22030, 22926)]
```

Comment: `data =list(map(int, map(float, ...)))`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but I get the following error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'map'

Comment: Sorry, edited the comment, now check.

Comment: Just to mention that there must be [better way](https://www.oracle.com/news/connect/building-location-based-applications-with-python-and-oracle.html) to deal with Oracle spatial data, than to manipulate string. This is clearly XY problem. Check https://www.oracle.com/news/connect/building-location-based-applications-with-python-and-oracle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern `('\([0-9., ]+\)` which will give you all tuples containing interger/float, convert string to tuple using `ast.literal_eval()`. Finally get list of tuples using `list(zip(out[::2], out[1::2])`

```
import ast
import re

out = re.findall('\([0-9., ]+\)', ip)[-1]
out = ast.literal_eval(out)
out = list(zip(out[::2], out[1::2])
print(out)

[(22027, 22943.23),
 (22026, 22939),
 (22025, 22936),
 (22025.09, 22932),
 (22027, 22929),
 (22030, 22926)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) 2 times with your splitting delimiters:

```
>>> out = ip.rpartition(split_string_1)[-1].rpartition(split_string_2)[0]
>>> out
"22027, 22943.23, 22026, 22939, 22025, 22936, 22025.09, 22932, 22027, 22929, 22030, 22926"
```

Then [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) over `", "` and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to `float`s; lastly take every 2 elements with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (i.e., odd indices and even indices in parallel) to form the output:

```
>>> out = list(map(float, out.split(", ")))
>>> out = list(zip(out[::2], out[1::2]))
>>> out

[(22027.0, 22943.23),
 (22026.0, 22939.0),
 (22025.0, 22936.0),
 (22025.09, 22932.0),
 (22027.0, 22929.0),
 (22030.0, 22926.0)]
```

Comment: can you please also show your `import` statements? what library contains `rpartition`?

Comment: @Ma0 No import needed, `rpartition` is a method of `str`ings. You can refer to the link. (in mobile it might not be so visible; if so please see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition)).

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, just replace the int with float, because you've got floating point numbers in your data

```py
data = list(map(float, ip.split(split_string_1)[1].split(split_string_2)[0].split(", ")))
result = list(zip(data[::2], data[1::2]))

print(result)
>> [(22027.0, 22943.23), (22943.23, 22026.0), (22026.0, 22939.0), (22939.0, 22025.0), (22025.0, 22936.0), (22936.0, 22025.09), (22025.09, 22932.0), (22932.0, 22027.0), (22027.0, 22929.0), (22929.0, 22030.0), (22030.0, 22926.0)]
```

A comment on your splitting:
If you're guaranteed to have a string of that form, you can perhaps just do the following:
1)Get rid of the last `)` character, `ip = ip[:-1]`
2)Split on '(' and take the last part, `ip = ip.split("(")[-1]`
3)Split this on comma, `ip = ip.split(",")`

```py
ip = ip[:-1].split("(")[-1].split(",")
data = list(map(float, ip))
result = list(zip(data[::2], data[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you define a method that does the operation, in this case it is returning a generator:

```
def each_slice(iterable, n=2):
    if n < 2: n = 1
    i, size = 0, len(iterable)
    while i < size-n+1:
        yield iterable[i:i+n]
        i += n
```

Once you have your list (letting apart the conversion of string to number):

```
lst = ['22027', '22943.23', '22026', '22939', '22025', '22936', '22025.09', '22932', '22027', '22929', '22030', '22926']
```

You can just call the method `each_slice(lst)`:

```
print(list(each_slice(lst)))
#=> [['22027', '22943.23'], ['22026', '22939'], ['22025', '22936'], ['22025.09', '22932'], ['22027', '22929'], ['22030', '22926']]
```

Note that this implementation cuts off the reminder elements, for example grouping by five:

```
print(list(each_slice(lst, n=5)))
#=> [['22027', '22943.23', '22026', '22939', '22025'], ['22936', '22025.09', '22932', '22027', '22929']]
```